# Reactive Form Validity based on IP Addresses RegEx

Tags: regex, angular, angular-reactive-forms

**Update:** I find that this behavior is reproducible using a simple regex such as `/^[0-9]+$/`. It is also reproducible using a custom validator function such as

```js
export function textareaPattern(pattern: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
        const values = control.value.split('\n');
        let mismatch = false;
        values.forEach(val => {
            mismatch = !pattern.test(val);
            if(mismatch) {
                return {textareaPattern: {value: control.value}}
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**Original post:** I have a regex that is intended to validate that a user has entered multiple, valid IP addresses- one per line- in a text area.

> /^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))?$\n?/gim

The regex works on a happy path, but gets weird once both a valid entry and an invalid entry are present.

If I enter all valid values, the form control is valid, as expected. Example:

```
10.1.121.2
10.2.121.3
10.3.121.4
```

If I enter all invalid values, the form control is not valid, as expected. Example:

```
butter
potato
123
```

If I enter a combination of valid and invalid values, the form control alternates between valid and invalid, depending on the length of the entry. If the entry's length is even, it's invalid, and odd is valid. How odd.

length: 12, Invalid

```
10.1.121.1
f
```

length: 13, Valid

```
10.1.121.1
fo
```

I'd think the problem lies in the RegEx, but I'll admit I'm far from comfortable deciphering such a behemoth of a RegEx.

The RegEx should match:

```
192.168.1.1
255.203.232.1
1.0.12.1
```

The RegEx should not match:

```
256.1.12.1
1934.1.22.3
201.foobar.201.1
```

Minimal, Reproducible Example **(updated with solution)**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v4f35a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The quality pun is much appreciated. I've tried the regex out [here](https://regex101.com/r/kAMO9p/1) , and it seems to work correctly. My guess is there's some issue with the script used to output true and false. Maybe you can check that again?

Comment: Also, if you sandwich an invalid input between two valid IPs, the output is false every 3rd character instead of every alternate character. Not sure if that's a good hint, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @RoboMop - I didn't notice the every-third-character bit, but I can repro. I found that the regex also worked as expected in Regexr, which leads me to think the issue could lie in Angular's Forms rather than the RegEx - not that I'm sold on that.

Far as the script for outputting true/false - that's simply a reflection of the form's Valid status, which hinges entirely on whether the contents of the textarea match the RegEx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this boiled down to two issues.

The first problem was that the `global` flag for RegExes causes the JS engine to track a lastIndex property from which the next search will start when `myRegex.test()` is called again. Since the regex object is the same throughout the validation process, that lastIndex is updated and referenced as you type, and the form re-validates.

The second problem is that without `global`, the form would be considered valid as long as one line is correct. So my input could be

```
192.168.foobar
192.168.1.1
hello world!
```

and the form is valid because of line 2.

**My Solution**

I've implemented a custom validator for textareas. It accepts my regex (sans `g` flag) and splits the contents of the textarea on `\n`. It immediately assumes no mismatches, then for each line, checks that the line matches the RegEx. If not, it mismatches and returns an object containing the contents of the textarea:

```js
import {AbstractControl, ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';

export function multilinePattern(pattern: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const values = control.value.split('\n');
    if (values.length === 1 && values[0] === '') {
      return null;
    }
    let mismatch = false;
    values.forEach((val: string) => {
      if (!pattern.test(val)) {
        mismatch = true;
      }
    });
    return mismatch ? {multilinePattern: {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}
```